# Create a priority queue with reverse order

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

I created a new class o object called Element, which has a lot of value 'degree'

```
class Element(object):
 def __init__(self, name, i):
  self.name = name
  self.degree = i
  # some other values

 #some other functions

 def __cmp__(self, other):
  return cmp(self.degree, other.degree)
```

And I want to create a priority queue containing this elements:

```
que = Queue.PriorityQueue()
que.put(Element('element1', 23))
que.put(Element('element2', 45))
que.put(Element('element3', 11))

while not que.empty():
 next_el = que.get()
 print next_el.name + " " + next_el.degree
```

And the program will print:

```
element3 11
element1 23
element2 45
```

But I want to have:

```
element2 45
element1 23
element3 11
```

So I want to make, that the element with bigger value of degree has higher priority and is taken first. 
And the second question is: if two elements has the same value of degree, in which order they will be taken?

Comment: Then compare them differently. Your first question wasn't really a question. The second question is: in whichever way you define the comparator. Equals will also have to return true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the comparison method of your `Element` class to reverse the order:

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
  return -cmp(self.degree, other.degree)
```

Negating the return of `cmp` reverses the queue, because `__cmp__` returns positive, negative or zero depending on the result of the comparison:

```
cmp(a, b) <  0: a <  b
cmp(a, b) >  0: a >  b
cmp(a, b) == 0: a == b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this method to compare:

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    return -cmp(self.degree, other.degree)
```

This will make `element1 < element2` if `element1.degree > element2.degree`